# How to add domain to the cart in whmcs via hook or api

Tags: whmcs

We are planning to post the domain name like example.com, that need to be automatically added to the cart. While we going to the register page or home page in whmcs.

Please let me know, how to fix the issue. If anyone already did like that, please share your knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask it on SO, go to a programmer hiring website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URL:

http://demo.whmcs.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&domains[]=typeyourdomainhere.com&domainsregperiod[typeyourdomainhere.com]=1

Source: [WHMCS Forums](https://forums.whmcs.com/showthread.php?93262-Add-domain-to-cart-without-additional-search)